# Creating a recursive schema in ajv

Tags: recursion, ajv

I am trying to create a schema for an object that may contain elements in an attribute that is of the same type as the original. What I mean by this is this:

```
{
    "id": "a",
    "type": "group",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "a1",
            "type": "group",
            "items": [
                {
                    ...
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "a1",
            "type": "single",
            "items": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to validate a potentially infinitely recursive structure of elements such as this using ajv?

Comment: It is possible. See https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/validating-data-with-json-schema-part-2--cms-25640